# How to cumul filters with logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm currently discovering elastic search, kibana and logstash with docker. *(Version 7.1.1)* The three containers are running well.

I have some data files containing some lines like this one:

```
foo=bar    type=alpha    T=20180306174204527
```

My logstash.conf contains:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/data/*.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  kv { 
    field_split => "\t"
    value_split => "="
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

I handle this data:

```
{
          "host" => "07f3051a3bec",
           "foo" => "bar",
       "message" => "foo=bar\ttype=alpha\tT=20180306174204527",
             "T" => "20180306174204527",
    "@timestamp" => 2019-06-17T13:47:14.589Z,
          "path" => "/tmp/data/ucL12018_03_06.txt",
          "type" => "alpha"
      "@version" => "1",
}
```

First step of job is done.
Now I want to add a filter to transform the value of the key `T` as a timestamp.

```
{
...
             "T" => "2018-03-06T17:42:04.527Z",
    "@timestamp" => 2019-06-17T13:47:14.589Z,
...
}
```

I do not know how to do it. I tried to add a second filter just after the `kv` filter, but nothing change when I add new files.

Comment: Perhaps this should work:  `date {
    match => [ "T", "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS" ] target => "T"
  }`

Comment: Thanks @baudsp ! It works when I add your line just after the closing bracket of kv filter. If you want, you can answer I validate your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this filter after the `kv` filter:

```
date { 
  match => [ "T", "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS" ] 
  target => "T"
}
```

The [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) filter will try to parse the field `T` using the provided pattern to create a date, which will be written to the `T` field (by default it overwrite the `@timestamp` field).